# expex + epltxchapno suppressing chapter numbers in memoir

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, counters, expex

I've run into a strange problem while using `expex` in the memoir class. Specifically, I want to reset the example numbering at the beginning of each chapter, so I use `\usepackage{epltxchapno}` as suggested in the manual. But this creates the following problem:

- Every `\chapter` is treated as if it is a `\chapter*` command -- no "Chapter #" is printed at the beginning of the chapter
- The chapter title for each `\chapter` is not included in the table of contents.

Here's a MWE and screenshots of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{epltxchapno}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title 1}
\ex
example 1
\xe 

\chapter{Title 2}
\ex
example 2
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image: First chapter]
[image: Second chapter]

Comment: Welcome! I suggest reporting it to the package maintainer. Memoir has been updated since `expex` (more than once), so probably the package has not yet been updated to cope with the changes.

Comment: @cfr Provided my solution holds up, there's no need for the ExPex supplied code in the first place.

Comment: @AlanMunn That doesn't seem a good reason not to report a bug.

Comment: @cfr well the bug is the whole bit of extra code, `epltxchapno.sty`, which is unnecessary. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I know that is what you mean and I think that is a particularly good reason to report it. Should be easy to attach a patch file, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use the ExPex numbering/tag system, so I'm not sure if the following solution captures referencing etc., but it certainly works for your posted example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{exnotype=chapter.arabic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\excnt=1}{}{}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Title 1}
\ex
example 1
\xe 

\chapter{Title 2}
\ex
example 2
\xe

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]